# Get all active directory groups of a user

Tags: 2010, development, active-directory, user

I have found many results on how to [get](https://christopherclementen.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/get-a-list-of-all-sharepoint-groups-users-including-active-directory-group/) [all](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2f4fc2bf-c37e-423c-8942-8a6c19b5b271/how-to-get-user-belongs-to-which-group-in-sharepoint-active-directory?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) [members](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93aa873b-3e9a-4174-83a7-9da82d066b66/sharepoint-2010-check-for-current-login-user-belongs-to-which-active-directory-group-and-display?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) of an AD group, but not the other way round.

How can I get all AD groups a given `SPUser` belongs to and not just the SharePoint groups of that user (with `user.Groups`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the below command to find out the user AD groups.

1. Run command promt as an admin.
2. Run command - `net user (userisid) /domain`

Comment: And how would this be done in code? I require this information on a WebPart I am developing...